# Composite clustered index vs non-unique clustered index. Which is better/worse in this case?

Tags: sql-server, performance, clustered-index

I have a database where all tables include a `Site` column (`char(4)`) and a `PrimaryId` column (`int`).

Currently the clustered index on all tables is the combination of these two columns. Many customers only have one site so in those cases I think it definitely makes sense to change the clustered index to only include the `PrimaryId`.

In cases where there are multiple sites though, I'm wondering whether it would still be advantageous to only use the `PrimaryId` as the clustered index? Might having a smaller clustered index produce better performance than having a unique one?

In case it's relevant, there are generally not going to be more than a few sites.  10 sites would be a lot.

Comment: You'd need to *measure* with *your* data sets and *your* query patterns to know for certain. There's no one-size-fits all answer.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever.  With the database I'm using at the moment it's definitely faster.  Just trying to strike a balance between doing my own testing and getting input from others.  Don't want to waste too much time if someone can provide a little guidance :)

Comment: which column is mostly use in where clause site field or primaryid ?
i think one with most use  in where condition should be clustered index.

Comment: @KumarHarsh PrimaryId, but very often they're used together.  No doubt that PrimaryId definitely needs to be in the CI.  I found that the UNIQUIFIER sql adds for non-unique indexes is 4 bytes.  Since that's the same size as the Site field I'm inclined to believe I may as well go with the composite CI at this point.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple UNIQUE index is always better then NON-UNIQUE. There is some maths behind it but the greater uniqueness is the faster server can look up a record from index.

CLUSTERED index is great as they physically order the records on disk and it always a good idea to use CLUSTERED INDEX on UNIQUE keys.

CLUSTER INDEX with PRIMARY KEY give very good performance with large data. If your data is not high in column then it will not matter much.

Comment: Yeah, I just happened to notice some queries were running faster when I switched it to just the PrimaryId.  But my test database isn't necessarily a good sample of what everyone is using so... that's why I'm asking.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Actually: in SQL Server, the clustered index **must be** unique (because that's the way each row in a table will be located - so it has to find every single row separately). If you don't make it unique yourself, SQL Server will add a 4-byte **uniquefier** "hidden" column to it to make it unique.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently read a article about how nonclustered indexes are matching table rows. I will try to summarize what I believe is relevant to your question.

There are two types of tables (in the context of indexes):

- heap - a table without clustered index
- clustered index - a table with clustered index

**In the first case** a nonclustered  index is matching rows using RIP-Based bookmarks which has the following format:

```
file number - page number - row number
```

and a nonclustered index is looking like this:

[image]

You can see the RIP bookmark is in red.

> Generally speaking, the rows of a heap do not move; once they have
>   been inserted into a page they remain on that page. To be more
>   technically-precise: rows in a heap seldom move, and when they do
>   move, they leave a forwarding address at the old location. The rows of
>   a clustered index, however, can move; that is, they can be relocated
>   to another page during data modification or index reorganization.

**In the second** the nonclustered index is using the index key of the clustered index as a bookmark and the clustered index itself should meet several criteria:

1. it must be unique
2. it should be short
3. it should be static

I am going to describe the first criteria (the others are described in the link below):

> Each index entry bookmark must allow SQL Server to find the one row in
>   the table that corresponds to that entry. If you create a clustered
>   index that is not unique, SQL Server will make the clustered index
>   unique by generating an additional value that "breaks the tie" for
>   duplicate keys. This extra value is generated by SQL Server to create
>   uniqueness is called the uniquifier and is transparent to any client
>   application. You should carefully consider whether or not to allow
>   duplicates in a clustered index, for the following reasons:
>
> 1. Generating uniquifiers is extra overhead. SQL Server must decide, at
>      insert time, if a new row's key is a duplicate of an existing row's
>      key; and, if so, generate a uniquifier values to add to the new row
> 2. The uniquifier is a meaningless piece of information; a meaningless
>      piece of information that is being propagated into the table's
>      nonclustered indexes. It's usually better to propagate a meaningful
>      piece of information into the nonclustered indexes.

The whole article can be found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/72281/).